# What is causing the pattern in Azure Service bus Metric?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am working on the Azure Service bus topic where more than one thousand messages are combining all the subscriptions in it. I didn't send or receive any message from that Service bus topic for a few days. After creating a Metric to see the Avg. Dead-letter Message in last 4 hours, I found there is a pattern where the plot was dropped a bit for every 75 mins as shown below:

[image]

What is causing this pattern? Is this problem due to any unavailability?